# can't install dependencies because of node and webpack version conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to install the dependencies with the exact version which are listed in json file, and I got errors below:

```html
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"^4.35.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.1.0" from terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev terser-webpack-plugin@"^5.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

since the dependencies with the required version are not the latest one, I downgrade my node.js from latest version 16 to 14+, and install with npm i --leacy-peer-deps, but the error shows still the same, seems the version from node or webpack still not compatible to the dependencies(Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"^4.35.3" from the root project).

how can I solve this problem?

here is the json list:

```js
{
  "name": "example-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack-dev-server  --config webpack.dev.js --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to delete package-lock.json and clear npm cache using 'npm cache clean -f' before npm i.**

Caret (^) notation: It will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0

Tilde ( ~ ): It will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.